# How can I solve this issue? AttributeError when trying to import Xarray

Tags: attributeerror, python-xarray

I am trying to import xarray to start my code but I do not know why I have this error.
[image]

I spent a lot of time trying to figure out the error but I couldn't. I already tried to update everything, install, uninstall etc but nothing seems to worked

Comment: Hi!! :) It would be great if you add your code and where it is failing and more descriptively is hard to find out what is your problem, and the text of the error here written too not only in image.

If you pass the code or a MRE (Minimum reproducible example) to test if works for us and can give you some solution or at least a new vision.